# Running SSH command from PHP gives sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified error even though NOPASSWD settings are done

Tags: sudo, apache-httpd, php, tty

I am using LAMPP to run apache server. From a php file I am executing a python script which executes `ssh`, `scp` commands. But I am getting error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I looked for this error and as per suggestions I created wheel group in `sudoers` file as:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL
```

In the `httpd.conf` file I have `user=apache` and I changed

```
Group=wheel
```

But still I am getting above error, not sure why. When I do `exec(whoami)` in php file it prints `daemon` so not sure with which user my php is getting executed.

Comment: Running *any* commands with root permission from web interface is not wise. You might as well install Apache as root.

Answer (score 1):

you have to  disable  requiring `tty` in your `sudoers` :

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```